# Cassandra: Precision of double values exported with COPY TO in a collection (map)

Tags: csv, cassandra, cql

How do I set the precision of a double value in a collection in the same way as a double column when exporting to a CSV file with COPY TO?

DOUBLEPRECISION works for the column (d below), but not for the key in the map.

```
CREATE TABLE test.digits (
    name    text,
    d       double,
    digits  map<double, int>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((name))
);

INSERT INTO test.digits (name, d, digits) VALUES ('Fred', 0.1234567890123456789,
    {
        1.1234567890123456789 : 1,
        2.1234567890123456789 : 2,
        3.1234567890123456789 : 3
    }
);

SELECT * from test.digits;

 name | d        | digits
------+----------+--------------------------------------
 Fred | 0.123457 | {1.12346: 1, 2.12346: 2, 3.12346: 3}

COPY test.digits (name, d, digits) TO 'digits.csv' WITH header=true AND DELIMITER='|' AND NULL='' AND DOUBLEPRECISION=15;

cat digits.csv
name|d|digits
Fred|0.1234567890123457|{1.12346: 1, 2.12346: 2, 3.12346: 3}
```

If it's not possible to set this precision in a collection, is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding: `AND FLOATPRECISION=15`

```
COPY my_keyspace.digits (name, d, digits) TO 'digits.csv' 
WITH header=true AND DELIMITER='|' AND NULL='' AND DOUBLEPRECISION=15
AND FLOATPRECISION = 16;
    
➜  cat digits.csv
name|d|digits
Fred|0.1234567890123457|{1.1234567890123457: 1, 2.1234567890123457: 2, 3.1234567890123457: 3}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, that works. I find it quite counter-intuitive that one must _sometimes_ specify the precision of a different type (float) in order to control the precision of a double, though... .

Comment: @jimstaffer I agree, please consider opening a Jira ticket.

Answer (score 0):

The cqlsh utility displays 5 digits of precision by default.

To enable more digits for the select, add or create a ~/.cassandra/cqlshrc file with:

```
[ui]
float_precision = 10
double_precision = 15
```

However, this will not resolve the COPY TO precision issue which seems like a bug in collections export as implied by @fg78nc.